# What is the most efficient way to compare to Dataframe columns and match the similar rows based on a function?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, performance

Assuming we have two Dataframes each containing a column of somewhat similar string-based values. What is the most efficient and/or effective way to match the rows with similar columns, based on a comparison function — like [textdistance's implementation](https://pypi.org/project/textdistance/) of Jaro-Winkler?

Example DataFrames:

```
first_df = pd.DataFrame( ['Cars and cats', 'Spaceship', 'Captain Marvel', 'Dune','Bucks in 6'], columns=['Title'])

second_df = pd.DataFrame( ['Captain Harlock', 'Cats and dogs', 'Buccuneers', 'Dune buggy','Milwaukee Bucks'], columns=['Title'])
```

What I'm thinking is:

- Creating a Cartesian Product based on each DataFrame's column of interest
- Apply the comparison function and store the result in a new column. Let's call it similarity_score
- Sort the new DataFrame by best value to worst (depending on the algorithm)
- Drop the duplicates of the column we are mostly interested in

Implementation:

```
comparison_df = first_df.merge(second_df, how='cross')

comparison_df['similarity_score'] = comparison_df.apply(lambda row: textdistance.jaro_winkler.normalized_similarity(row['First DataFrame Titles'], row['Second DataFrame Titles']), axis=1)
display(comparison_df)

comparison_df = comparison_df.sort_values('similarity_score', ascending=False).drop_duplicates(subset=['First DataFrame Titles'], keep='first')
```

Any suggestions are welcome. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What are the sizes of the dataframes? I don't see major flaw in current approach - maybe using `multiprocessing` for speed up.

Comment: @AndrejKesely, each DataFrame has a sub-thousand size, so it takes some time to generate the Cartesian Product. I thought of using Dask or Pandarallel to speed things up. I couldn't find an example of a Cartesian Product in Modin.

Comment: The cartesian product is computed in `O(n^2)` time. The problem is you seems to want a `O(n^2)` matrix in output so there is no way to improve the complexity based on that. Using parallelism (efficiently) is hard because of strings and the CPython GIL and string manipulation is rather slow. Rewritting a faster implementation my help but I think the actual problem is the complexity.

Comment: @JérômeRichard, it is indeed a matter of complexity. I'm playing around with Dask, which seem to have a good solution for just data like the above with [Bag.product](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/bag-api.html#dask.bag.Bag.product).